# How to avoid using max() in implementation of Value Iteration?

Tags: python, dictionary, max, reinforcement-learning

On this page you'll find the Value Iteration algorithm. http://artint.info/html/ArtInt_227.html

I have implemented the table Q(s,a) using dictionary of dictionary. In Python:

```
q = {s: {a: value}}
```

Now, the problem is, I have to find max value of a list of Q(s,a) and it is really costly. I have profiled my code and almost 80% time is spent on {built-in method max}.

Is there any clever way to avoid it?

Comment: If at any given time, `max` operation is the only operation you need, I would suggest you to change you data structure. Try using a `max-heap` which you can manually code or use some `Python` library. You can put in your custom comparison function into that heap and the max element always remains the root.

Comment: All operations in the heap will be O`(lg n)`. Is that satisfactory enough?

Comment: I resolved the problem by storing the max value in a dictionary. O`(1)` in access. Thanks by the way.

Comment: But what about cases when you need to access the previous maximum element? You don't have a history stored in that case? Is your system always incremental in nature?

Comment: No, I don't think I need a history. Have you seen the algorithm, what do you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70610/discussion-between-activatedgeek-and-user74158).

Comment: Can you post a snippet of that? I currently only loop through the available s,a and compare to current max; would like to see how you’ve done it.

Comment: Define a new dictionary called max_values = {s: (max_value, best_action)}. Every time you compute new_q_value for s and a, compare the new_q_value with max_values[s][0]. If the new q_value is larger than this value, then do max_values[s] = (new_q_value, a).